# Problem locating the element for a filter pane 'pencil Icon' using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am working on a business intelligence dashboard. On the filter pane, they all have a pencil icon that you can click to edit that specific filter. The issue is that all 12 filters have the same element. How do I select the individual filter pencil? 
`<div class="ew-i-fx ew-i-act f-act" data-ng-click="levelMainAction($event, level, $index)" data-ng-show="!item.disabled &amp;&amp; !item.locked" data-ng-class="{running: opened.edit == 'l'+$index}" data-translate="" data-translate-attr-title="we.actions.editfilter" title="Edit Filter"></div>`

[image]

Comment: maybe you can use driver.findelements() method which returns collection of element and once you get the elements collection then you can select the icon based on index value. Something like this : List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements();   elements.get(1).click();

Answer (score 0):

If all the attributes of all the filters are same and if the position of the filters are not changing, then you can use index to identity the filter.
You can use the below xpath to find the element and change the index value accordingly:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@title='Edit Filter'])[1]"));
```

Comment: Hi, Tried the code and it did not work, Do you have any other idea

Answer (score 0):

For each of these icon I am sure there must be a text or label or title associated to it on the left.

For example -

Filter Name 1 ---- icon

Filter Name 2 ---- icon

and so on...

What you will have to do is first locate "Filter Name 1" element and then locate next icon associated to it.

Will be helpful if you could add more details into your post to show the Filter names and their HTML code.

Basically the HTML above / before

```
<div class="ew-i-fx ew-i-act f-act" data-ng-click="levelMainAction($event, level, $index)" data-ng-show="!item.disabled &amp;&amp; !item.locked" data-ng-class="{running: opened.edit == 'l'+$index}" data-translate="" data-translate-attr-title="we.actions.editfilter" title="Edit Filter"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, Tried this and it did not work, Do you have any other idea

Comment: @PeaceT If you could provide additional relevant HTML code I may be able to provide more suggestions. You can rename the filter names in the html code if you wish to, keep the structure intact.

Answer (score 0):

If you sure with the elements having same properties : By.xpath("(//div[@title='Edit Filter']) and it more than one, then collect them by :

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//div[@title='Edit Filter']));
```

And the use indexValue to get the element you want :

```
int indexValue = 1;
elements.get(indexValue).click();
```

Comment: Hi, Tried the code and it did not work, Do you have any other idea

Comment: @PeaceT did you not get any elements in the List? or you were not able to perform any action in the elements? And if you got the elements list then how many elements did you get?